# AttributeError when making a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using the discord.py library to create a bot for my Discord server. At the moment I'm trying to handle what happens when a user removes their reaction from a message. I've updated Discord to the latest version, allowed intents both using the Developer Portal and through code like so:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('$', '?'), intents=intents)
```

Here's the code for the on_raw_reaction_remove function:

```
    channel = 867854256647176252
    message = 867855236861132860
    if payload.channel_id == channel and payload.message_id == message:
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        emoji = payload.emoji
        global channels
        channels = str(channels)
        channels = channels.split()
        if str(emoji.name) == '' :
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Offtopic')
            for index in range(len(channels) - 1, -1, -1):
                if channels[index] == 'Offtopic':
                    channels.pop(index)  
            await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
```

And the error it yields once the reaction is removed:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/meri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 420, in on_raw_reaction_remove
    await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

None of the answers to similar problems managed to help with the situation, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoneType means that the value you're accessing (`payload.member`) is set to None, and therefore has no `remove_roles()` function. You defined member above as its own standalone variable, so did you intend to do `member.remove_roles()` instead?